# Show multiple tcpdump outout within one wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I know how to use wireshark to show one tcpdump result using ssh. But now I want to debug kubernetes network. There will be multiple nodes and I need to capture all the packets. So I must run tcpdump on each nodes. Is it possible to combine tcpdump output and show in one wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark.html) can merge capture files.  Refer to the section on [Merging capture files](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOMergeSection.html) in the Wireshark User Guide for all the information you need.  Alternatively, you can use the [`mergecap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html) command-line tool, which is part of the suite of Wireshark command-line tools, to merge the files.  There may be other tools of interest that can probably help you here as well; try searching for "*merge*" on the [Wireshark Tools wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools).

Comment: But I want live capture. Not merging pcap files.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a solution.
Using gretap to connect all hosts into one bridge. And use tc mirror to mirror all packets to this bridge. Then just capture this bridge, I can get all the packets now.